# To measure the importance of a number in a list

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

A list of number as below. They are the revenues of 30 individual sales managers.

[3,1,4,1,2,3,3,2,4,1,5,1,3,1,1,2,2,1,5,4,9,7,10,10,10,10,9,7,8,7,9,7,10,12,14,15,15,11,15,11,11,11,13,18,16,16,19,16,16,20,16,24,22,25,25,22,22,27,28]

Mean: 11

Standard Deviation: 8

Plot the numbers in a histogram of bin size 5, it's like this.

[image]

I want to find out the contribution of each sales manager in the population, by their individual revenues.

Trying the Z-score: calculated by (Number - Mean) / Standard Deviation, and turn as a list.

[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2]

The list of number is not of normal distribution. And, it shows some negative numbers. So I suspect Z-score is not a proper way.

What's the best way to measure the importance of a number in its list?

Is it a decent way to score them 1 to 100? (when the length of list >= 100)

Thank you.

Comment: why not the number itself?

Comment: @carlo, thanks for the comment. the actual list might contains more than 1000 numbers so I want to score the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to find out the contribution of each sales manager in the population, by their individual revenues.

Can't you just divide each contribution by the total? So you get the contribution as a percentage. In R this would be:

```
sm <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 22, 22, 24, 25, 25, 27, 28)

sm / sum(sm) * 100
[1] 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.32 0.32 0.32 0.32 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.48 0.64 0.64 0.64 0.80 0.80 1.13 1.13 1.13 1.13 1.29 1.45 1.45 1.45 1.61 1.61 1.61 1.61 1.61 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.77 1.93 2.09 2.25 2.41 2.41 2.41 2.57 2.57 2.57 2.57 2.57 2.89 3.05 3.22 3.54 3.54 3.54 3.86 4.02 4.02 4.34 4.50
```

This is saying that the managers with sales 1 contribute by 0.16% and the one with 28 contributes by 4.5%

Comment: thanks for the help. Is it a decent way to score (integer) them (roughly) 1 to 100?